# Expression to extract part of an address

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have a column of addresses and want to separate into several parts.
Ex. house number, street name, city, zip. For example lets say I have a cell with this string: `'111 Example St, City, State 89786 zipcode, country'`. This is how I'd like to separate it:

```
house_numb | street_name | city | state | zip | country |

'111' | 'Example St' | 'City' | 'State' | '89786' | 'US'
```

I was able to use a left regex expression to create the house number. Since the city, zip, state, and country are the same I was able to populate those columns as well. But I cannot seem to get the street name in the string. What expression can be used to extract the street name?

I tried `regexp_substr( "Text", ';(\\d*)\}' )` and replaced the `';'` with `' '` and `'}'` with `','` and did not get the street name between the first space and the first comma.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe some Python list and string functions can help.

```
temp = text.split(',')
```

makes an array of everything that was separated by commas.

```
temp[0]
```

contains '111 Example St'

```
temp2 = temp[0].split()
```

splits by spaces and contains ['111', 'Example','St']

```
temp2[1:]
```

contains ['Example','St']

```
' '.join(temp2[1:])
```

contains 'Example St'